Left center aligning table with landscape environment
I'm trying to align this landscape table to the bottom left of the page - like you would see with a landscape table in a book. I can't get anything to work - I've tried different values for table - [b] etc, and tried using vspace, etc. I have to do it using pdflscape
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{flushleft}
\caption{Sample Model with Filler Text \label{tab:sample-full}}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c}
\hline
 & Var1 & Var2 & Var3 & Var4 & Var5 \\
\hline
Category A             & $0.10 \; (0.03)^{**}$   & $0.02 \; (0.05)$       & $0.06 \; (0.05)$        & $0.16 \; (0.04)^{***}$  & $0.08 \; (0.04)^{*}$   \\
Category B             & $-0.45 \; (0.09)^{***}$ & $-0.41 \; (0.15)^{**}$ & $0.02 \; (0.15)$        & $-0.04 \; (0.11)$       & $-0.08 \; (0.10)$      \\
Category C             & $-0.17 \; (0.05)^{**}$  & $-0.09 \; (0.08)$      & $-0.03 \; (0.08)$       & $-0.15 \; (0.06)^{*}$   & $0.12 \; (0.06)^{*}$   \\
Category D             & $-0.04 \; (0.04)$       & $-0.02 \; (0.06)$      & $-0.07 \; (0.06)$       & $-0.06 \; (0.04)$       & $0.01 \; (0.04)$       \\
Category E             & $-0.02 \; (0.03)$       & $0.05 \; (0.05)$       & $-0.03 \; (0.05)$       & $0.13 \; (0.04)^{***}$  & $-0.01 \; (0.04)$      \\
Category F             & $-0.02 \; (0.08)$       & $0.13 \; (0.13)$       & $-0.19 \; (0.13)$       & $-0.04 \; (0.10)$       & $-0.05 \; (0.09)$      \\
Category G             & $0.08 \; (0.08)$        & $0.23 \; (0.14)$       & $-0.40 \; (0.14)^{**}$  & $-0.18 \; (0.10)$       & $-0.09 \; (0.09)$      \\
Category H             & $-0.04 \; (0.04)$       & $0.01 \; (0.06)$       & $0.01 \; (0.06)$        & $-0.05 \; (0.04)$       & $0.07 \; (0.04)$       \\
Variable X             & $0.04 \; (0.02)$        & $-0.01 \; (0.03)$      & $0.13 \; (0.03)^{***}$  & $0.05 \; (0.02)^{*}$    & $0.01 \; (0.02)$       \\
Variable Y             & $0.18 \; (0.02)^{***}$  & $0.11 \; (0.04)^{**}$  & $-0.22 \; (0.04)^{***}$ & $-0.11 \; (0.03)^{***}$ & $0.03 \; (0.03)$       \\
Variable Z             & $-0.02 \; (0.04)$       & $0.00 \; (0.06)$       & $0.05 \; (0.06)$        & $0.00 \; (0.05)$        & $0.04 \; (0.05)$       \\
(Intercept)            & $2.43 \; (0.16)^{***}$  & $3.40 \; (0.25)^{***}$ & $1.96 \; (0.25)^{***}$  & $2.79 \; (0.18)^{***}$  & $1.90 \; (0.18)^{***}$ \\
\hline
Log Likelihood         & $-2388.17$              & $-3167.45$             & $-3198.72$              & $-2692.68$              & $-2600.56$             \\
N (Individuals)        & $2143$                  & $2070$                 & $2070$                  & $2143$                  & $2143$                 \\
N (Groups)             & $1848$                  & $1785$                 & $1784$                  & $1848$                  & $1848$                 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Standard errors in parentheses.} \\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\emph{{***}p < 0.001; {**}p < 0.01; {*}p < 0.05}}
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\mbox{}\vfill
\begin{table}[htbp]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\caption{Sample Model with Filler Text \label{tab:sample-full}}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c}
\hline
 & Var1 & Var2 & Var3 & Var4 & Var5 \\
\hline
Category A             & $0.10 \; (0.03)^{**}$   & $0.02 \; (0.05)$       & $0.06 \; (0.05)$        & $0.16 \; (0.04)^{***}$  & $0.08 \; (0.04)^{*}$   \\
Category B             & $-0.45 \; (0.09)^{***}$ & $-0.41 \; (0.15)^{**}$ & $0.02 \; (0.15)$        & $-0.04 \; (0.11)$       & $-0.08 \; (0.10)$      \\
Category C             & $-0.17 \; (0.05)^{**}$  & $-0.09 \; (0.08)$      & $-0.03 \; (0.08)$       & $-0.15 \; (0.06)^{*}$   & $0.12 \; (0.06)^{*}$   \\
Category D             & $-0.04 \; (0.04)$       & $-0.02 \; (0.06)$      & $-0.07 \; (0.06)$       & $-0.06 \; (0.04)$       & $0.01 \; (0.04)$       \\
Category E             & $-0.02 \; (0.03)$       & $0.05 \; (0.05)$       & $-0.03 \; (0.05)$       & $0.13 \; (0.04)^{***}$  & $-0.01 \; (0.04)$      \\
Category F             & $-0.02 \; (0.08)$       & $0.13 \; (0.13)$       & $-0.19 \; (0.13)$       & $-0.04 \; (0.10)$       & $-0.05 \; (0.09)$      \\
Category G             & $0.08 \; (0.08)$        & $0.23 \; (0.14)$       & $-0.40 \; (0.14)^{**}$  & $-0.18 \; (0.10)$       & $-0.09 \; (0.09)$      \\
Category H             & $-0.04 \; (0.04)$       & $0.01 \; (0.06)$       & $0.01 \; (0.06)$        & $-0.05 \; (0.04)$       & $0.07 \; (0.04)$       \\
Variable X             & $0.04 \; (0.02)$        & $-0.01 \; (0.03)$      & $0.13 \; (0.03)^{***}$  & $0.05 \; (0.02)^{*}$    & $0.01 \; (0.02)$       \\
Variable Y             & $0.18 \; (0.02)^{***}$  & $0.11 \; (0.04)^{**}$  & $-0.22 \; (0.04)^{***}$ & $-0.11 \; (0.03)^{***}$ & $0.03 \; (0.03)$       \\
Variable Z             & $-0.02 \; (0.04)$       & $0.00 \; (0.06)$       & $0.05 \; (0.06)$        & $0.00 \; (0.05)$        & $0.04 \; (0.05)$       \\
(Intercept)            & $2.43 \; (0.16)^{***}$  & $3.40 \; (0.25)^{***}$ & $1.96 \; (0.25)^{***}$  & $2.79 \; (0.18)^{***}$  & $1.90 \; (0.18)^{***}$ \\
\hline
Log Likelihood         & $-2388.17$              & $-3167.45$             & $-3198.72$              & $-2692.68$              & $-2600.56$             \\
N (Individuals)        & $2143$                  & $2070$                 & $2070$                  & $2143$                  & $2143$                 \\
N (Groups)             & $1848$                  & $1785$                 & $1784$                  & $1848$                  & $1848$                 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Standard errors in parentheses.} \\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\emph{{***}p < 0.001; {**}p < 0.01; {*}p < 0.05}}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}


